# Django CMS, there is a piece of HTML in the include, how to include this piece twice on one page and so that you can change different content?

Tags: django, django-cms

There is a template in the include / cards folder

```
{% load cms_tags %}
{% load static %}
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card__item">
        <div class="card__top">
            {% placeholder 'card__top_c1' %}
        </div>
        <div class="card__foot">
            {% placeholder 'card__foot_c1' %}
        </div>
    </div>
   .........
</div>
```

I connect this piece on one page twice, is it possible somehow that one include had one content, and the other has another ????

it just turns out if I change something in the first, then it changes in the second, what can be done ???

```
{% include './include/cards.html' %}
<br><br>
{% include './include/cards.html' %}
```

Comment: You have to do it via if-else statements or you can create multiple html and include separate html in 2nd condition

Comment: otherwise, nothing?

Comment: There might be some other way .But I have attached snippet using if-else for your reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using if-else. Check the snippet

**Models.py**

```
class modelname(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=(
        ('Top', 'top'),
        ('Footer', 'foot')
    ))
```

**Cards.html**

```
{% load static %} 
{% if modelname.position == 'top' %}

<div class="card" >
  <div class="card__top">
    {% placeholder 'card__top_c1' %}
  </div>
</div>

{% else %}
<div class= "card">
     <div class="card__foot">
          {% placeholder 'card__foot_c1' %}
     </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```